# Redirect OpenWrt outbound traffic to external proxy

Tags: proxy, openwrt, mitmproxy

I am trying to force a WiFi router with OpenWrt to send traffic to a mitm proxy.

I see that it is possible to [install a proxy alongside OpenWrt](https://openwrt.org/docs/guide-user/services/proxy/start) on the router, but I'm not clear if that's the right solution or how to configure it.

Specifically, I want to install OpenWrt onto a wireless access point and have all the inbound wireless traffic sent to a proxy.

More specifically

- Android app connects to WiFi
  (setting a proxy on the Android wifi interface typically only proxies browser traffic and doesn't work in my case)
- Traffic is handled by OpenWrt on the router.
- Traffic is sent from OpenWrt to [OWASP Zap](https://owasp.org/www-project-zap/) on an external machine for inspection.

I understand certificate pinning etc and this is not a problem.

If it's relevant, my target router is a [Netgear EX3700](https://www.netgear.com/uk/home/wifi/range-extenders/ex3700/), with one WiFi and one Ethernet interface.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can use the proxy to route the traffic to the proxy by the socks5, and using the v2ray to route the traffic to mitmproxy. Thats what I have done.